# Assigning object variables to array in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to pre-define my object variables into an array. After that, I need to access one element at a time from that array and assign a value to it. Like so:

```
$obj = new StdClass();
$arr = ["$obj->item1"];
$arr[0] = "apple";
print_r($obj); // expecting to see $obj->item1 = apple
```

I know I'm doing something wrong above, but could not figure out what.

Comment: you’re overwriting `$arr[0]`, instead of assigning the property of $obj. What’s probably messing you up is that objects pass by reference; but arrays by value.

Comment: If you assign just the object to `$arr[0]`, then you might possibly be able to set `$obj->item1` somewhere else in the code, and then reference `$arr[0]->item1`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Thanks to the hint from Tim Burton

```
$arr = [&$obj->item1];
```